# After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04 proccessor fan always on

Tags: ubuntu, fan, dell-inspiron, lm-sensors

I recenlty upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04, before the upgrade the fan speeds were normal and rarely got loud. After the upgrade the fan is always on. I searched for a fix and found out that sensors ouputs something weird. One of the sensors is detecting +511.0 C.

```
iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +31.0°C  

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 3970 RPM
CPU:            +41.0°C  
Ambient:        +41.0°C  
SODIMM:         +32.0°C  
Other:          +36.0°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +511.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +40.5°C
```

Is there something I can do or should i take my laptop to warranty(note that the laptop had windows 10 installed, I got ubuntu on it myself)

Comment: try installing the proprietary driver on the video card

Answer (score 0):

Did a shutdown and went away for an hour, after the most recent boot the fans were working same as before the upgrade.